# Angular *ngFor y ui semantic accordion no funciona. Si quiero usar ngfor, no se despliega la parte content

Tags: angular7, semantic-ui, accordion, ngfor

Os paso mi ejemplo HTML.

```
<div class="ui container accordion" *ngFor="let hilo of hilos" >   

            <div class="title">
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                ENFERMEDAD: {{hilo.enfermedad}} PREGUNTA: {{hilo.pregunta}}
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p class="transition hidden"> RESPUESTA: {{hilo.respuesta}}</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

un ejemplo de accordion sin *ngfor se me despliega sin problemas. Pero si pongo o quiero hacer un accordion usando *ngfor ( al principio) no se despliega.

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="ui container accordion">
```

Si lo separo y lo pongo lo primero, funciona. Gracias.